# Sass deprecation warning on mixin that converts px to rem

Tags: css, sass

I have a mixin that converts px to rem. I've recently been getting the following deprecation warning when I try build. Can anyone suggest a fix.

DEPRECATION WARNING on line 135 of 
source/css/partials/global/mixins.scss:
The result of `0px == 0` will be `false` in future releases of Sass.
Unitless numbers will no longer be equal to the same numbers with units.

```css
@function parseInt($n) {
    @return $n / ($n * 0 + 1);
}

@mixin rem($property, $values) {
    $px: ();
    $rem: ();
    @each $value in $values {
        @if $value==0 or $value==auto {
            $px: append($px, $value);
            $rem: append($rem, $value);
        }
        @else {
            $unit: unit($value);
            $val: parseInt($value);
            @if $unit=="px" {
                $px: append($px, $value);
                $rem: append($rem, ($val / 16 + rem));
            }
            @if $unit=="rem" {
                $px: append($px, ($val * 16 + px));
                $rem: append($rem, $value);
            }
        }
    }
    @if $px==$rem {
        #{$property}: $px;
    }
    @else {
        #{$property}: $px;
        #{$property}: $rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the deprecation warning you need to remove the units when comparing with a number. You can easily remove the units using you own `@function` `parseInt`:

So you need to add this little trick to your `@mixin`:

```
@mixin rem($property, $values) {
    $px: ();
    $rem: ();
    @each $value in $values {
        // divide $value by 1 to remove the units in the comparison 
        @if parseInt($value) == 0 or $value == auto {
            $px: append($px, $value);
            $rem: append($rem, $value);
        }
        @else {
            $unit: unit($value);
            $val: parseInt($value);
            @if $unit=="px" {
                $px: append($px, $value);
                $rem: append($rem, ($val / 16 + rem));
            }
            @if $unit=="rem" {
                $px: append($px, ($val * 16 + px));
                $rem: append($rem, $value);
            }
        }
    }
    @if $px==$rem {
        #{$property}: $px;
    }
    @else {
        #{$property}: $px;
        #{$property}: $rem;
     }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented your update and it still seems to give the same warning.

Comment: @user3486427 which compiler are you using? So i can test with the same one.